# CDF in a discrete simulation (Jerry banks book)

Tags: probability, self-study, simulation, random-variable, cumulative-distribution-function

Consider the experiment of tossing a single die. Let $X$ be number of spots on up face of die after toss. Then range space of $X$ is $R_x = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. The discrete probability distribution for this experiment is:

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
x_i & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
p(x_i) & 1/21 & 2/21 & 3/21 & 4/21 & 5/21 &6/21 \end{array}

Now the author has given a table for the above experiment with its cdf (Cumulative distribution function), but I don't understand how it is produced. The table is

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
x  & (-\infty,1) & [1,2) & [2,3) & [3,4) & [4,5) & [5,6) & [6, \infty)\\
F(x) & 0 & 1/21 & 3/21 & 6/21 & 10/21 & 15/21 & 21/21 \end{array}

How is the $F(x)$ value calculated ?

Comment: Why $/21$ and not $/6$? and what is it you want removed?

Comment: @peter--- Absolutely a right thought. I also thought this, but the author has given this table directly and when i looked again and again i saw " X be number of spots", so i think the author has taken Sample space as 21 instead of 6, as there are 21 spots in 1 die

Comment: @PeterFlom--- i want to understand how the F(x) i.e. CDF value is removed ?

Comment: One possible interpretation of this setting is that the author contemplates tossing a *loaded* die.  The first table specifies the chances of each face: clearly it's loaded so that faces with more pips have a greater chance of appearing. (As a check, note that the probabilities sum to unity, as they ought: $1/21+2/21+\cdots+6/21=1$.)  The second table merely presents the same information as a CDF. The question is a little difficult to comprehend, though, because it is not apparent that anything is "removed." What do you mean by that?

Comment: @whuber----- sorry for my bad english, what i meant was how is F(x) calculated ? I will edit that.

Comment: Have you reviewed the author's definition of cdf and tried to apply that to this example?

Comment: @whuber--- Yes the author says "CDF denoted by F(x) measures the probability that the random variable X assumes a value less than or equal to 'x' i.e. F(x)= P(X <= x)" ( i think where 'x' is the possible outcome from a sample space, say for above example it could be 1 pips or 2 pips etc )

Comment: @whuber----The author says that if X is discrete random variable than F(x) = summation of p(xi) for all xi <= x where p(xi) is probability mass function(PMF) and xi is the possible outcomes. p(xi) is given in 1st table

Comment: @whuber--- The author says that all probability questions about X can be answered in CDF terms. For example P(a<X<=b) = F(b) - F(a) for all a < b

Comment: R122, I asked that question as a hint to you: you needn't reproduce the text in comments! Now it's time for you to apply the definitions you quoted to this example.

Comment: @whuber-- sorry for that. But i am unable to get the answer, could you atleast give an hint

Comment: Draw a graph of the CDF using the definition. Hint: it looks like a staircase. It comes from $-\infty$ with a zero value, then it arrives at $x=1$ and it... jumps! That is what the definition says. Now, what is the size of the jump? Please, draw the graph. You're getting confused about the intervals in the authors second table.

Comment: @Zen--- but to draw a graph we require values and these values are present in the table and my doubt is regarding these values i.e. how to get these values

Comment: To draw the graph you just need the values of the **first** table. Do you understand the **first** table?

Comment: @Zen--- Yes the graph looks like a staircase and the author has drawn that,but he has considered the second table for the drawing the graph i.e. F(x) i.e. CDF on Y-axix versus x on X-axis

Comment: @Zen--- Yes i do understand the first table, the only problem is that the author has directly written the CDF value in table 2 i.e. F(x), i want to know how to calculate this F(x) ? Anyways thanks

Comment: The second table is just one way to describe the graph of the CDF.

Comment: It seems that you are having a hard time understanding the **definition** of the **Cumulative** Distribution Function. Try this, since $F(x)=P\{X\leq x\}$, what is the value of, say, $F(2.5)$?

Comment: Isn't true that $F(2.5)$ is the probability of $X$ being less than $2.5$? But that is the same thing as saying that $X$ is equal to $1$ or $2$, right? And those are exclusive alternatives. So, what is $F(2.5)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wasting around 5-6 hours this is what I have understood, is that correct?

In table 2, I need to find out different values of $F(x)$ depending on the value of $x$. So for example, when $x=[2,3)$ we have $F(x)=3/21$. This is how the answer came :

Since $[a,b)$ is a semi-open interval which means my $x$ value will be $$ a \leq x < b $$ therefore $x=[2,3)$ will be $$ 2 \leq x < 3 $$ i.e. I will take values equal to 2 and greater than 2 but less than 3 i.e. 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, ..., 2.9. But since the pips or spots on a die can never be in fraction or decimal point, all values except 2 are discarded and we get only 2 i.e. $F(2)$. According to the definition of CDF $$ F(x) = \sum p(x_i) \text{   for all } x_i \leq x $$

Therefore $F(2) = p(1) + p(2)$ which can be obtained from Table 1, i.e. $F(2) = 1/21 + 2/21 = 3/21$.

Am I correct?

@Zen--- Therefore I think $F(2.5)$ is still $F(2)$ therefore answer is again 3/21. Correct?

Comment: Correct. Good job.

Comment: @Zen-- Thanx man for your help.